# What should be stateobject in pushstate()?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

`state object` — The state object is a JavaScript object which is associated with the new history entry created by `pushState()`. Whenever the user navigates to the new state, a popstate event is fired, and the state property of the event contains a copy of the history entry's state object.

can anyone explain be what is `state object` and how should i use it some simple example will help.

Comment: i m trying to use funtion name but it showing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should contain any information your JavaScript needs to restore the page to the state it was in before you changed the DOM and updated the URL.

Comment: can it be a funtion